# What does the underscore(_) do in for loop Golang?

Tags: go

I am just getting started learning the Golang language!
In for loop, I saw sometimes adding an underscore or without underscore.

Whatever add _ or not, I got the same result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    doSomething()
    sum := addValues(5, 8)
    fmt.Println("The sum is", sum)

    multiSum, multiCount := addAllValues(4, 7, 9)
    fmt.Println("multisum", multiSum)
    fmt.Println("multiCount", multiCount)
}

func doSomething() {
    fmt.Println("Doing Something")
}

func addValues(value1 int, value2 int) int {
    return value1 + value2
}

func addAllValues(values ...int) (int, int) {
    total := 0
    for _, v := range values {
        total += v
    }
    return total, len(values)
}
```

```
func addAllValues(values ...int) (int, int) {
    total := 0
    for v := range values {
        total += v
    }
    return total, len(values)
}
```

All I know is I don't care about the index. Is that all? or there is something more what I have to know??

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The result is not the same though: it's `multisum 20` vs `multisum 3`.

Comment: Basically it is called the blank identifier which, in case of a for-loop, ignores the variable. Here is a thorough answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764432/4809932

Comment: @bereal Oh yeah you're right... I missed a huge thing. When I check the result again, I got a different result. I'm still figuring out why I got different result

Comment: @bereal For now, I know why I got a different result! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "\_," (underscore comma) in a Go declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764421/what-is-underscore-comma-in-a-go-declaration)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `range` over *slices*:

1. In `for v := range values {` the `v` is the index of the element in the slice.
2. In `for _, v := range values {` the `v` is the actual element value.
3. In `for i, v := range values {` the `i` is the index and the `v` is the element.
4. In `for i, _ := range values {` the `i` is the index of the element in the slice.

You can run [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/fINUtdV9AZa) example to see the differences.

---

```
Range expression                          1st value          2nd value

array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
string          s  string type            index    i  int    see below  rune
map             m  map[K]V                key      k  K      m[k]       V
channel         c  chan E, <-chan E       element  e  E
```

For more details see the [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the variable that iterates in the loop, you can use `_` to simply let Go ignore it:

```
mySlice := [int]{1,3,4,59,5}
for _,x := range mySlice {
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By placing underscore you are telling the compiler this:
Ok, I'm aware that this function is returning something but I don't care! For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    mul1, add1 := test_function(2, 3)
    fmt.Println(mul1, add1)

    mul2, _ := test_function(4, 5)
    fmt.Println(mul2)

    _, add3 := test_function(7, 8)
    fmt.Println(add3)
}

func test_function(a int, b int) (mul int, add int) {
    return a * b, a + b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add to the amazing answer above:
I think one of the main benefits is to maintain readability in your program: if you replace the blank identifier with a variable then you have to use it or your program will not compile.
also this decrease memory allocation be neglecting one of the returned parameters...