# Does the assignment to blank identifier lead to resource leak in Go?

Tags: go, memory-leaks

What if I acquire some closable resource (e.g. `*os.File`) and assign it to the blank identifier (`_`)? According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24357102/6093952), *there is no way to access this variable so it will be optimised out of the resulting program*. But will it be closed correctly? Example code below.

```
func check(path string) bool {
    _, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter if you assign the file to the blank identifier or to a named variable, if you don't call its [`Close()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Close) method **explicitly**, it will not be closed and will leak resources.

If you assign the returned `*os.File` to the blank identifier, you can't refer to it thus you can't call its `Close()` method. So **don't** do it.

Comment: But after assigning to `_` I can't close it explicitly, so we have something like dangling pointer here. Or can I?

Comment: @hant0508 Yes, if you assign it to `_`, you can't refer to it, so you can't call its `Close()` method. So **don't** do it.

Comment: os.File has a finalized on it that closes the file descriptor, so in this case there is not a leak (in an amortized sense) but this _type_ of thing could cause a leak.

Comment: @jdizzle That's good to know, but `runtime.SetFinalizer()` documents that there is no guarantee the finalizers will run.

Comment: @jdizzle, that is also an implantation detail of one specific runtime, and nothing defined by the Go language.

Comment: @jdizzle: Note that the amortized sense might not be sufficient, too, just in a practical sense. Suppose some process (on a Linux-y system) is running with an open-files limit of 10 or 100 files, and we `check` a thousand files. Will we GC some of the "lost" `*os.File` objects before we run out of fd's, or not? Probably not, in this case.